# How do I get the last three digits of a varying length column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to write a select statement and get the last three digits of all of the rows in a column for which the length varies.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Hypothetical column:

```
12312398098098 
127865275
```

I want the resulting column to have the values:
Resulting column after the script:

```
098
275
```

Comment: What is the datatype of this column please? Edit: Ah actually doesn't matter I was thinking `YourCol % 1000` but that won't preserve leading zeroes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(4000), [hypothetical column]), 3) FROM table;
```

(Added a convert in case this is a numeric column.)

Comment: Thank you so much!! I would upvote you but I have to be rank 15. I'm fairly new to stack over flow...

Comment: ...although I don't like your use of `[hypothetical column]`, as that implies embedded spaces and [brackets] are a good idea.

Comment: Why are [brackets] a bad idea? They protect you from other users' bad naming conventions (whether columns have spaces, which are allowed, or are reserved words, keywords, etc. which unfortunately are also allowed).

Comment: `CONVERT` will happen implicitly if numeric

Comment: @Martin while true, this is another case where I prefer to be explicit. The next step might be to try to do [column a] + [column b] in which case those numeric columns should be converted *before* concatenation or applying string-based functions.

Comment: My apologies for not specifying, it is not a numeric column so the convert isn't needed in my case but if it was a numeric column I don't suppose it is a bad idea to convert. Thank you for your help.